# Why is my Strict-Transport-Security Header in .htaccess not working?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, https, http-headers, response-headers

I am trying to add the **Strict-Transport-Security** Header to my .htaccess file inside of my web root. After adding it and reloading my website I cannot see it in the response headers. For the record, my rewrites are working. Just not sure why the header is not.. In case it matters, I am using a VPS through GoDaddy. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" env=HTTPS

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: This is working fine to my Apache 2.4. Most likely it is due to VPS. Is `http://example.com` redirecting to `https`?

Comment: Yes the redirect is working. It just seems to be the Header that doesn't work. Not just this Header but i've tried other security Headers and they don't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html):

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"
```